# How to encapsulate JSON object to implement multiple parameters when HttpGet and HttpPost method is requested in WebApi?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

If there are multiple parameters to pass to a `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` method in Web API, how can we always pass JSON objects so that it's easier to handle it both client-side and server-side?

Comment: Have you already gotten your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In WebApi project, get or post multiple parameters on a controller, we will find it not easy to solve it clearly, actually, there is a simple and pragmatical solution if we use json and dynamic object.

**1.HttpGet**

We can append json string in the query string content, and parsed the json object in server side.

```
var data = { 
     UserID: "10", 
     UserName: "Long", 
     AppInstanceID: "100", 
     ProcessGUID: "BF1CC2EB-D9BD-45FD-BF87-939DD8FF9071" 
};  
var request = JSON.stringify(data);  
request = encodeURIComponent(request); 

//call ajax get method 
ajaxGet:
 ...
 url: "/ProductWebApi/api/Workflow/StartProcess?data=", 
 data: request,
 ...


[HttpGet]  
public ResponseResult StartProcess()  
{  
    dynamic queryJson = ParseHttpGetJson(Request.RequestUri.Query);  
    //begin to parse...
    int appInstanceID = int.Parse(queryJson.AppInstanceID.Value);  
    Guid processGUID = Guid.Parse(queryJson.ProcessGUID.Value);  
    int userID = int.Parse(queryJson.UserID.Value);  
    string userName = queryJson.UserName.Value;  
    ...
} 

private dynamic ParseHttpGetJson(string query)  
{  
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            var json = query.Substring(7, query.Length - 7);  // the number 7 is for data=
            json = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(json);  
            dynamic queryJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);  

            return queryJson;  
        }  
        catch (System.Exception e)  
        {  
            throw new ApplicationException("wrong json format in the query string！", e);  
        }  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

**2.HttpPost**

**2.1 Simple Object**

We passed json object with ajax, and parse it with dynamic object in server side. it works fine. This is sample code:

```
ajaxPost:

...
Content-Type: application/json,
data: {"name": "Jack", "age": "12"}
...


[HttpPost]
public string ParseJsonDynamic(dynamic data)
{
    string name = data.name;
    int age = data.age;

    return name;
}
```

**2.2 Complex Object**

The complex object means that we can package **list** and **dictionary** object, and parse them with dynamic object in server side. We call this composite pattern.

```
var jsonData = {
   "AppName":"SamplePrice",
   "AppInstanceID":"100",
   "ProcessGUID":"072af8c3-482a-4b1c‌​-890b-685ce2fcc75d",
   "UserID":"20",
   "UserName":"Jack",
   "NextActivityPerformers":{
        "39‌​c71004-d822-4c15-9ff2-94ca1068d745":
         [{
            "UserID":10,
            "UserName":"Smith"
         }]    //list nested in dictionary
   }
 }

//call ajax post method
ajaxPost:
...
Content-Type: application/json,
data: jsonData
...

[HttpPost]
public string ParseJsonComplex(dynamic data)
{
   //compsite object type:
   var c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectTypeHere>(data.ToString()); 

   //list or dictionary object type 
   var c1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ComplexObject1 >(data.c1.ToString());

   var c2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< ComplexObject2 >(data.c2.ToString());

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use several parameters, create a class (ViewModel/VM) that have the parameters you need pass and the pass for parameter. Thus you will have a good run.

Example:

**Before**

```
[HttpPost]
public Json GetPass(string p1, string p2)
{
...
}
```

**Now**

```
Public class VMExample{
     public String p1 { get; set; }
     public String p2 { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public Json GetPass(VMExample parameters)
{
...
}
```